# Postgres INSERT is taking huge time to complete for huge volume of data

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, performance, insert

I have a SQL query as:

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable(SubjectID, CriteriaID)
SELECT customerid AS SubjectID
    ,0 AS CriteriaID
FROM (
    SELECT PC1.customerid
    FROM customer.ACCOUNT PC1
    WHERE (PC1.utilization < 1.1)
    ) src
```

The database is Postgres in AWS. The query executes for hours and sometimes in 5 to 6 minutes which is strange. The DB CPU utilization is steady below 80%.
The table `ACCOUNT` has huge volume of data like 12345678. The DB `Explain` plan shows proper usage of indexes.

Please suggest what other parameters needs to be checked to improve the performance of this query. `temp_file_limit` is 10GB.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4QjC.jpg)

Comment: Please include the query plan also, we can’t say what’s happening there without having more information

Comment: Looks like a something locked one of the tables and your query has to wait. Did you check pg_stat_activity?

Comment: Yes I have checked. There is no contention.

Comment: Please provide proper information for this performance question as outlined here: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3299/3684